# How to express event offset using Timing?

Tags: hl7-fhir

How can I express the following condition using Timing: "make some prescription **three days after** encounter start date, 1 tab x 3 times per day"?

(I understand how to express the latter part of the expression, as the authors provided Timing documentation with an example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [relativeDate](http://build.fhir.org/extension-relative-date.html) extension allows you to specify a date as relative to some other date.

Comment: Thanks but relativeDate is still in draft status.But I see the Timing.repeat.boundsDuration field. Is it possible to express 3 days offset as repeat.boundsDuration.low = 3d?

Comment: No.  Duration.low has to be a proper dateTime.  Any support for relative date/times is going to be in draft status and the final outcome is almost certain to be an extension as it's not something that "most" systems that support timings deal with.  The specified extension is the current authoritative solution to this issue.  

Note - "3d" wouldn't be sufficient anyhow as it wouldn't tell you 3 days from what.

Answer (score 0):

HL7 Pharmacy Work Group is planning changes to the Dosage type used in FHIR to support "conditional doses" such as this one.  Currently this is not supported in FHIR.